# how to decode a json in php

Tags: php, json

Here is my json,

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":15},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "abert",{
        "numFound":10,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":5,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"albert",
            "freq":126},
          {
            "word":"aber t",
            "freq":317},
          {
            "word":"alert",
            "freq":58},
          {
            "word":"a bert",
            "freq":13},
          {
            "word":"abort",
            "freq":57},
          {
            "word":"a be rt",
            "freq":1045},
          {
            "word":"avert",
            "freq":37},
          {
            "word":"ab e rt",
            "freq":335},
          {
            "word":"aberr",
            "freq":21},
          {
            "word":"ab er t",
            "freq":317}]},
      "enstin",{
        "numFound":10,
        "startOffset":6,
        "endOffset":12,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"einstein",
            "freq":92},
          {
            "word":"ens tin",
            "freq":44},
          {
            "word":"enshrin",
            "freq":13},
          {
            "word":"en s tin",
            "freq":673},
          {
            "word":"enjoin",
            "freq":12},
          {
            "word":"e ns tin",
            "freq":335},
          {
            "word":"entwin",
            "freq":8},
          {
            "word":"ens t in",
            "freq":317},
          {
            "word":"epstein",
            "freq":8},
          {
            "word":"en st in",
            "freq":231}]},
      "correctlySpelled",false,
      "collation",[
        "collationQuery","albert einstein",
        "hits",154,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",[
          "abert","albert",
          "enstin","einstein"]],
      "collation",[
        "collationQuery","(aber t) einstein",
        "hits",375,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",[
          "abert","aber t",
          "enstin","einstein"]],
      "collation",[
        "collationQuery","albert (ens tin)",
        "hits",335,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",[
          "abert","albert",
          "enstin","ens tin"]],
      "collation",[
        "collationQuery","albert enshrin",
        "hits",137,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",[
          "abert","albert",
          "enstin","enshrin"]],
      "collation",[
        "collationQuery","alert einstein",
        "hits",139,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",[
          "abert","alert",
          "enstin","einstein"]]]}}
```

I am trying to get the following field

```
"collation",[
        "collationQuery","albert einstein",
        "hits",154,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",[
          "abert","albert",
          "enstin","einstein"]],
```

specifically 'albert einstein'. I tried the below code, but getting an error.

```
$myArray = json_decode($response, true);

foreach ($myArray['collation'] as $doc) {
echo $doc[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of problems here.

1. Collation is not a root-level field of the JSON. `responseHeader`, `response`, `spellcheck` are the root-level fields. Everything else is nested under them. Do `print_r($myArray)` for what `json_decode` is parsing out.
2. `$myArray` is an object, not an array. Objects are accessed like `$myArray->response`, not `$myArray['response']`.
3. What you're calling "a field" is not a field. `json_encode` sees the structure of that data as:

   ```
               [6] => collation
               [7] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => collationQuery
                       [1] => albert einstein
                       [2] => hits
                       [3] => 154
                       [4] => misspellingsAndCorrections
                       [5] => Array
                           (
                               [0] => abert
                               [1] => albert
                               [2] => enstin
                               [3] => einstein
                           )

                   )
   ```

If this is your code outputting the JSON, you're going to need to structure it much better. If it's someone else's code, they're mean.

Comment: This is the response returned by solr

Comment: The Solr devs are mean, then. Looks like they have an open bug on it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3029

Comment: can you pls provide some suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You're going to have to have your code step through `$myArray->spellcheck->suggestions` piece by piece, detect the string 'collation', and then consider the *next* piece of data to be the collation data. It's a nasty format and whoever made it output JSON like this should be kicked in the crotch.